# Некорректная иконка Cordova App в переключателе приложений под Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap, icon

Приложение собрано под Cordova.
Все иконки прописаны.
Но в переключателе приложений все равно показывается дефолтовая иконка.
Кто сталкивался? Как лечить?

[image: дефолтовая иконка]

```
<icon src="res/icon.png" />
<platform name="android">
    <icon src="res/android/icon-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/icon-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/icon-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/icon-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/icon-xxhdpi.png" density="xxhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/icon-xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
    <splash src="res/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/android/splash-port-xxhdpi.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/android/splash-port-xxxhdpi.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

В итоге выяснилось что если до установки своих иконок загружал на устройство приложение с дефолтными, система запоминает иконки где-то у себя внутри и подсовывает в некоторых случаях старые.

Проверить легко - достаточно собрать приложение с новым бандл id и посмотреть что будет.